# php value from db table subtracted by multiple row values in different table

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling to work out how to get the original `entitlement` figure from table1 and then subtract the 'days' from each request from table2 in start date order.

1st table gets their entitlement figure

2nd table gets the requests

Any guidance would be appreciated, the output i am looking for is:

```
Start Date       End Date       Days to be taken        Days remaining

-                   -                   -                      22

01 Sep 2011      03 Sep 2011            3                      19
10 Sep 2011      11 Sep 2011            2                      17
```

**Here is my code:**

```
$is_business_result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM holiday_entitlement_business_manual WHERE employee = \'' . $username . '\' AND academic_year = \'' . $acyear . '\' ');

if($is_business = mysql_fetch_array($is_business_result)) {
echo '<div style="float:left; width:400px;">';
echo '<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td><strong>Name:</strong></td>
<td>'.$is_business['employee'].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Entitlement:</strong></td>
<td>'.$is_business['entitlement'].' '.$is_business['units'].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Department / Division:</strong></td>
<td>'.$is_business['division'].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Line Manager:</strong></td>
<td>'.$is_business['line_manager'].'</td>
</tr>
</table>';
echo '<br/>';
echo '<br/>';
echo '<br/>';    
echo '</div>';





echo '<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td><strong>Start Date</strong></td>
<td><strong>End Date</strong></td>
<td><strong>Days to be taken</strong></td>
<td><strong>Days remaining</strong></td>
</tr>';

echo '<tr>';

echo '<td>-</td>';
echo '<td>-</td>';
echo '<td>-</td>';
echo '<td>'.$is_business['entitlement'].'</td>';

echo '</tr>';







}

$requests_result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM requests WHERE employee = \'' . $username . '\' AND approved = 1 AND academic_year = \'' . $acyear . '\' ORDER BY start_date ASC');

while($requests = mysql_fetch_array($requests_result)) {

$start_date = new DateTime($requests['start_date']);
$end_date = new DateTime($requests['end_date']);

$timestamp_start_date = $start_date->getTimestamp();
$timestamp_end_date = $end_date->getTimestamp();

$formatted_start_date = date("d M Y", $timestamp_start_date);           
$formatted_end_date = date("d M Y", $timestamp_end_date);           

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$formatted_start_date.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$formatted_end_date.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$requests['days'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}

echo'</table>';
```

**TABLES**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `requests` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `academic_year` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `employee` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `end_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `days` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `approved` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `holiday_entitlement_business_manual` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `academic_year` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `employee` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `full_part_time` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `weekly_hours` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `division` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_commencement` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `entitlement` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `units` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `line_manager` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `length_of_service` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `band` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `new_entitlement` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `weekly_entitlement` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=227 ;
```

Comment: what is the relation b/w these tables??

Comment: please add a description of your mysql tables

Comment: relationship would be employee and academic year, this is done in the SQL SELECT

Comment: ?? Modified question with tables

Answer (score 0):

i guess employee is a foreign key if it is then you can join two tables based on employee and then get all the data and  subtract the days count from entitlement in php